# Does the uuid from lsblk -f need to match uuid in /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, encryption, fstab, uuid

Ouput from lsbk -f

```
NAME                    FSTYPE      LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
loop0                   squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/47
loop1                   squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-calculator/406
loop2                   squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop3                   squashfs                                                 /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
loop4                   squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop5                   squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
loop6                   squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-characters/272
loop7                   squashfs                                                 /snap/core/6964
loop8                   squashfs                                                 /snap/core/6350
loop9                   squashfs                                                 /snap/core18/970
loop10                  squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-system-monitor/81
loop11                  squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop12                  squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-logs/61
loop13                  squashfs                                                 /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop14                  squashfs                                                 /snap/vlc/770
loop15                                                                           
sda                                                                              
├─sda1                  vfat              5DC3-6837                              /boot/efi
├─sda2                  ext4              221d0605-673f-4f51-ab00-07b418d864b5   /boot
└─sda3                  crypto_LUKS       d35532b2-9210-4b59-b924-39b4fb8b93e8   
  └─sda3_crypt          LVM2_member       n24ztS-ci1Y-MeOh-6d2F-B731-Ym5n-ArDnee 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   ext4              8edfdfac-c9a2-45d8-939d-7024d7747c23   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 swap              a8c5d6f0-8f11-4a2f-b47b-453ff9421923   [SWAP]
```

Output from fstab (as root)

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=221d0605-673f-4f51-ab00-07b418d864b5 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5DC3-6837  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the contents of `/etc/fstab` as well as the output of the command `lsblk -f` *as plain, code-formatted text*. The devices you're looking at in the disk utility have nothing to do with any of your fstab entries that are configured by UUID.

Comment: Yes, the UUID's in /etc/fstab need to match, and it appears that yours do. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: it wasn't a problem, sometimes what comes up on google isn't the same 'English', in any case, i have bigger problem now as my laptop has gone into a bootloop, i have just posted another question lol